# How to expand(odata-webapi) all the properties without passing $expand in query string in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am using odata v5.7.0 for webapi(vb.net).I need all the properties of object should be expanded without using $expand property on the query string.

Ex: http://localhost:26209/ProductList?$expand=customers/products

into

http://localhost:26209/ProductList

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you would want to do that and there might not be a clear cut way to achive it.Still if you want to get all the products for a customer you will have to go one at a time by using something like this.

`http://localhost:26209/ProductList/customers('customer_id')/products`

Else if you are using OData 2 there is an EntitySet for every association, so you an directly query the `products` EntitySet and use `$filter` instead. The URL will look similar to

`http://localhost:26209/Products?$filter=CustomerId eq *`

You can check $filter conventions [here](https://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/uri-conventions/)